# I try to print array of integer after I used memcpy in c

Tags: c, unix

Here is my code I tried also to do casting in mmap but it didn't work.
I need that after I use in memcpy *src include array of the shared from integer type and that printf print array of integer(the pid in code). with %d in printf the code not compile and when I use 5p its print me hexadecimal address

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
    
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int shared[3];
            
    void* src = mmap(0,num, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (src == MAP_FAILED)
    {     
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap() failed\n");     
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    //placement of shared array and print
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        {
            perror("fork error\n");
        }
        else
        {
            //Placement of pid to shared array
            shared[i]=getpid();
        }
        //need to change the permission in map, create a virtual memory
    }
    memcpy(src,shared, num+1);
    printf("%d\n",src);
    close(fd);  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a fork bomb. Because the code does not have different code paths for parent and child processes which means every child (and their children and their children, etc) also calls`fork`.

Comment: It looks to me like what you wanted to print was something like `*(int *)src`, not merely `src`?  As it stands you are trying to print the address of the shared region, not the data that you stored there.

Comment: Also you left out how `num` is defined and initialized, but it looks like there may be some mixup between number of `int`s and number of bytes.

Comment: And you realize that the array you've called `shared` is **not** shared?  Each child process will get its own copy.

Comment: i mean i want to print the pid that in the shared array

Comment: `src` is shared. `shared` is not shared. And presumably you want the parent process to do the printing. But there is no synchronisation code to ensure the children have run before the parent does the printing.

Comment: [*revised comment*] Your code does not compile. You didn't define `num`, `f`d, or `pid`. You also used a `%d` format to print a value of type `void*`; the correct format is **`%p`**. I doubt that you need all those headers for this example. Please provide a [mre].